# JCA Adapter Packaging

Tags: java, packaging, jca

I have a question regarding packaging of a JCA adapter. I have packaged a few jar files inside my JCA adapter rar file. I am using Weblogic. I would like to know whether the jar files placed inside this rar package are put on the Weblogic class path.

Can other aplications running on the same Weblogic server access classes inside those jar files?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a solution and hope this would help anyone looking for the same answer. After configuring the followings in **weblogic-ra.xml**, classes inside the JCA adapter RAR file are exposed to the system class path.

```
<wls:enable-access-outside-app>true</wls:enable-access-outside-app>
<wls:enable-global-access-to-classes>true</wls:enable-global-access-to-classes>
```